# Two classes' properties are the same, how can I can merge them into one?

Tags: css

For example:

```
.music {
    text-align: center;
    ...
}
.index {
    text-align: center;
    ...
}
```

(ps: `.music.index{}` doesn't work. )

Comment: Aside: `.music.index{}` targets `<element class="music index">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should separate the classes using comma `,`.

```
.music, .index {
    text-align: center;
    ...
}
```